# Find a file (case insensitive) and get the real file name (case sensitive) back in a variable

Tags: linux, unix, filenames

I know I have a file.
I know this file is Hello.txt, or HeLLo.txt, or HEllo.txt, or other case variation

So I can find this file by using:

```
find . -iname hello.txt
```

And it finds it.

How can I put the real name ("HelLO.txt") in a linux variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var=`find . -iname hello.txt | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\///g'`
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Just to documentate for other readers: header -n1 takes the first result, and sed '...' applies a regular expression so that it captures only the filename and not the whole path

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method:

```
var=`find . -iname hello.txt`
```

note that this assign ALL matching filenames to the variable, so if you've got multiple variants (Hello HeLLO hello HELLO, etc...), you'll get all of them in the var.

Comment: Wouldn't that return the whole path?